# Saving objects To NSDefaults in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use `NSDefaults` for saving objects. 
I want to save an object which contains properties, that point to another object which **inherits from NSObject** and contains properties like `NSString` and etc...


How can I do it?

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "user.h"

@interface dataManager : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)user* user;
@end
```

```
@interface user : NSObject
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* userName;
@property (assign,nonatomic)int age;
@end
```

I want to save `dataManager` to `NSDefaults` and it's properties as well (regardless the number of them).

Comment: can't you just use setObject:forKey?

Comment: Your classes will after confirm to `NSCoding` or [`NSSecureCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSSecureCoding_Protocol_Ref/index.html) and archive your custom object, since [`NSUserDefaults` can only accept certain types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have it persistent - your objects need to implement [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) protocol:

For example for "user" class add those functions, and in header add  protocol information

.h

```
@interface user : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.userName forKey:@"userName"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.age forKey:@"age"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userName"];
        self.age = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"age"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I have to implement it to any object that is property of the dataManager? and then what it will automatically enecode it

Comment: yes it will do that while saving to a file / loading from file